# Use 2 bootstrap class for table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a HTML table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
```

My question is if there is option in the same time to use another class in parallel like:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the class name with the existing classes like :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
```

And it will apply both effects.